# what is the meaning of data-300-center-center in data attribute html

Tags: html, parallax, skrollr

I have the following html

```
<p data-300-center-top="transform: scale(0.8); opacity: 0" 
   data-300-center-center="transform: scale(1); opacity: 1">
```

Which I use with [skrollr.js](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)

I don't understand what or why I use the number 300 for in the attribute `data-*-center-center`  and `data-*-center-top`.

Comment: What? Where? When? What are you talking about? Please, Please, read the guide [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask again..

Comment: i want to create a parallax design and using skrollr.js..
<p data-300-center-top="transform: scale(0.8); opacity: 0" data-300-center-center="transform: scale(1); opacity: 1">

this is the html data attribute what i'm asking

Comment: I've edited your question so it makes a bit more sense. You might really want to go over [ask] and [mcve] as well as the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before you post your next question. Keep in mind that question bans are hard to come by

Comment: @Portal_Zii the first revision was utter crap .. all votes are deserved

Comment: Sure but obviously this person is new. You could have educated them without killing the lil rep they have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the [docs](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#absolute-mode-or-document-mode):

> The syntax is `data-[offset]-[anchor]`, where offset can be any integer (0 is default) and anchor can be either start (default) or end. Either offset or anchor can be omitted in some situations. Here are some examples of key frames and their meaning.

For example:

> `data-bottom-center` = `data-0-bottom-center`: When the element's center is at the bottom of the viewport, thus the upper.

So in your case:

`data-300-center-top` means that element's center is `300px` below the top of the viewport.

Comment: thanx For the help @Mosh